# Python binary search always returns target not found value

Tags: python, search, binary-search

I've written the following code to do a binary search for a value, `target`, in a list or tuple, `collection`.

```
def binary(collection, target):
    """Binary search
    Takes a sorted list or tuple, collection, then searches for target
    Returns -1 if item isn't found. """
    length = len(collection)
    minimum = 0
    maximum = length - 1
    while minimum <= maximum:
        pivot = (minimum + maximum) // 2
        if collection[pivot] is target:
            return pivot
        elif collection[pivot] > target:
            minimum = pivot + 1
        else:
            maximum = pivot - 1
    return -1
```

As you can see, when `target` isn't found in `collection`, the function returns -1. No matter what I've done, the function has returned -1.

```
>>> test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> binary(test, 5)
-1
>>> binary(test, 1)
-1
```

What's causing this problem?

Comment: *Although the basic idea of binary search is comparatively straightforward, the details can be surprisingly tricky* — Professor Donald Knuth.

Comment: Is there any topic that Donald Knuth doesn't have a quote on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have this condition backwards:

```
elif collection[pivot] > target:
```

Switch it and the search works:

```
elif collection[pivot] < target:
```

For what it's worth, I figured this out by adding a printout to your search to see what's happening. When in doubt, add a printout:

```
>>> binary([1, 2, 3], 1)
(min=0, max=2, pivot=1)
(min=2, max=2, pivot=2)
     ^ Oops

# After fixing...
>>> binary([1, 2, 3], 1)
(min=0, max=2, pivot=1)
(min=0, max=0, pivot=0)
```

By the way, the built-in [bisect module](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html) performs binary searches. You don't have to write your own, unless you're doing it for educational value.

Comment: Educational value, purely. I sort of banged it out based on what I remembered a binary search to be.

Comment: I took a look at the bisect module and it seems that `bisect_left()` can work as a binary search with slight modification. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: The last time I tried to write my own binary search it took me around 10 iterations to get the stupid thing working. Off-by-one errors are my kryptonite. :-)

Comment: While we're talking binary search, would it be better to raise a ValueError rather than return -1 if the value isn't found? I feel like if someone used this and didn't read the source or docstring, they'd feed it into a list index and get an index when the value wasn't found (since -1 is a valid index)

Comment: Even the Python library can't make up its mind: `str.find` returns -1, `str.index` raises ValueError. Although `list` only has `index`, so maybe that breaks the tie.

Comment: Oh well, doesn't really matter since this isn't production-grade code or anything...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to correcting your condition test to `elif collection[pivot] < target:` , you used the "is" operator for testing whether you have found your target item:

```
    if collection[pivot] is target:
```

You should use "==" instead:

```
    if collection[pivot] == target:
```

Using "is" tests whether two things are actually the same object.  In Python, quite often small string and integer objects turn out to be stored and recycled, so this might work.  However, in most cases, it will not:

```
>>> a='abc'
>>> id(a)
2129839392
>>> b='ab'
>>> b+='c'
>>> id(b)
2129963136
>>> a
'abc'
>>> b
'abc'
>>> binary([a],a)
0
>>> binary([a],b)
-1
```